# Adobe In-Design in C# or in Java

Tags: java, c#, adobe-indesign, indesign-server

How to make document of Adobe in-design without opening the application in c# or Java.

I am able to create the document but for that, I have instantiated the UI of Adobe in-design

Below is the code I tried which is working but for this application need to be instantiated.

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InDesign.Application.CC.2019", true);
dynamic app = System.Activator.CreateInstance(type,true);InDesign.idScriptLanguage.idJavascript, new object[] { "" });
Document document = app.open("D:\\ResumeInDesign.indd", false);
```

Comment: Do some research into "InDesign Server".

Answer (score 1):

You can use [InDesign Server](https://www.adobe.com/products/indesignserver.html) to accomplish what you are wanting. The sdk is in `c++`, so look [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12191/Accessing-Adobe-InDesign-CS-COM-Objects-from-NET) for information on how to use the sdk in a .NET application.

Comment: The link you share opens the Application Adobe In-Design, and my requirement is to achieve the creation of the document without opening the application.